# How to fully remove edge from springy.js and raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael, springy.js

I'm trying to do a javascript application using springy and raphael.
In fact I forked demo-raphael.html (available from official springy code)
https://github.com/dhotson/springy/blob/master/demo-raphael.html

What I'm trying to do is to have 2 main nodes A and B and 10 others nodes (C, D, E, ...).
theses 10 nodes can be connected to A or B. (but not both in the same time)
If I do check some checkbox, some node can change their connection and go to the other main node.

So what I do seems to work except that she line between for example A and C is not removed.
When the checkbox is updated, I do run:

I suppose that A is connected to C and i want to disconnect it and connect B to C. Let's call EC this edge.
So I do run

```
graph_removeEdge(EC);
delete EC;
EC = graph.newEdge(C, B, {color: '#00A0B0'});
```

The code seems to work because B and C are connected, and A and C are not anymore. 
BUT I still can see old picture of the line between A and C ( it wont move anymore, but it's still there)

How can I remove that ?

I also tried to not delete and create this EC edge, but trying to update it with changing his target node, but nothing happen.
code:

```
EC.target = B;
```

One more question is how can I put a maximum distance between A and B.
Because they can be very close.

thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the problem:
springy is creating node and edge, but it also create a raphael path associated to this edge.
So This path has to be removed before destroying the edge

```
EC.connection.fg.remove();
graph_removeEdge(EC);
```

Note: The second question about putting a maximum distance between A and B: it can't be done without modification in springuy library because there is no link between A and B, so we cannot set a distance.
The only solution is to add a flag for each node, and nodes with this flag will then be distributed. Of course, this has to be implemented by a modification in springuy.js, probably in this function:

```
Layout.ForceDirected.prototype.tick = function(timestep) {
    this.attractToCentre();
    this.applyHookesLaw();
    this.applyCoulombsLaw();
    this.applyDistanceToFlaggedNode(); // <--- your new function
    this.updateVelocity(timestep);
    this.updatePosition(timestep);
};
```